# Select two columns using select query and then update the columns with results

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

In my employees table I am i have two columns area_code and BusinessPhone I stript the area code out and and put into an alias column and I did the same with the phone number. Now I need to update area_code and BusinessPhone columns with the results of what I have up into my alias columns but not sure how to do this.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT Right([BusinessPhone],3) AS Expr1, Mid([BusinessPhone],5) AS Expr2
FROM employees;
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what the data in `BusinessPhone` looks like? Unless I'm misunderstanding shouldn't `Expr1` be `Left([BusinessPhone]), 3)`

Comment: BusinessPhone is an orignial column in the database but the data in it has an area code with it I am splitting the area code from it and putting it into a alias column name then I would like to take the the results from the alias column and update the original columns with the results.

Comment: I understand that but your `Right([BusinessPhone],3)` takes the last 3 digits as area code. If your data looks like `555-3456789` then you could do left 3 to get the area code and right 7 for the rest.

Comment: I did this select query and it works fine I am stuck on how to update the same table with the result from temporary columns that I have created in the same table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you would perform the update. I still refer to my comments since we don't know exactly what the original businessphone looks like.

```
UPDATE Employees
SET area_code = right([BusinessPhone],3),
    businessphone = Mid([BusinessPhone],5)
```

Comment: Thanks that works I hate that when I over think things.